# Why would option chains' IV differ, for the same stock and expiration?

Tags: implied-volatility

I believe that the right-hand side refers to options sold before [CHK split its stock on Apr 15 2020 1 for 200](https://www.stocksplithistory.com/chesapeake-energy/). 1. But why do the IV differ so much, e.g. at the strike price of 3?

2. Why hasn't this difference in IV been arbitraged?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are the IV numbers  all over the map?

Are the quotes from real time?  If delayed, they're useless.  Some of them could be stale (last option trade occurred at a much earlier time). If closing quotes, bid/ask spreads widen significantly after the close, distorting price relationships.

The put spreads are reasonable compared to the call spreads, some of which are 2 to 4 dollars wide.  Where is the actual market on the call side?

How does the provider calculate IV?  Last trade?  Midpoint?

The best that I can offer is that if the difference could be arbitraged, it would be arbitraged.  The disparities exist so that means it's likely due to one of the possibilities that I mentioned.